# Location API. Get areas of a city

Tags: geolocation, location

Answer to this question could be very easy and I might end up feeling foolish for asking this but still...

Is there an API that gives me prominent areas/localities of a city? Workflow in my mind is

1. Get lat-long from a user's device
2. Resolve the city based on lat-long (This is done)
3. Get the important localities/areas of the city
4. Give these area names as options to user to select from.

Is there any API that can help me automate step 3?

Comment: I hope you find what you're looking for, but - from the off-topic flagging menu: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: I believe Google Places will give you what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: What device are you looking at? If you use the android set, geocoder library shall provide your an accurate location info based on gps. If web solution, you may get a web service solution at http://www.ipinfodb.com or DB solution at http://lite.ip2location.com

Answer (score 0):

This post may help in someway [GeoNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434642/find-all-localities-regions-of-a-city)